# Package installed globally via npm is not visible in cmd

Tags: node.js, npm, polymer, ubuntu-18.04

```
$ npm install -g polymer-cli
/home/kishore/.npm-global/bin/polymer -> /home/kishore/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/bin/polymer.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ polymer-cli@1.7.4
updated 1 package in 8.834s
```

```
$ polymer --version
polymer: command not found
```

Comment: How did you install node and is npm's `node_modules/.bin` parth of the path?

Comment: try running: `echo $PATH` and see what it's there. And also compare those folders against `which node` and `which npm`.

Comment: Thanks! I got it!

Comment: How did you get it? What was the issue? If you found a soution to your problem please add your own answer so that it may help somebody else out facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I specified the path $PATH to the directory where the global packages are installed!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use it yet as it is still in development mode. and instead can try Lit[https://lit.dev/][1]

to install you can try with yarn if npm is not working. both are pretty much same thought.